# Deny direct access to php files

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I wrote this code to redirect everything to index.php.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
```

I want to somehow adjust `!-f` to allow `.php` files to be 301 redirected to `/` without getting into a redirection loop. I have `/foo/bar/218` that loads `index.php` which requires `view/foo_bar.php`. I want `/view/foo_bar.php` to be inaccessible via the address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these rules:

```
# redirect .php requests to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=302]

# existing rules without .php files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.php$ index.php [QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Could you tell me, what this part `[\s?]` does?

Comment: Sure `[\s?]` is called character class in regex that matches a whitespace OR literal `?` after `.php`